# Load content dynamically in bootstrap 2.3 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing some modifications with twitter bootstrap modal and I am trying to achieve dynamic image loading in modal window. Also when the certain image is loaded I would like to be able to swipe between images. Can anyone help me with this one?

Here is structure:

```
<!-- Image trigger -->
<div class="item">
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="modal-trigger">
        <img src="img/7.jpg" alt="">
     </a>
</div>

<!-- Modal window -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

<!-- it makes empty spaces clickable -->
<div type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</div>

<img data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" src="http://placehold.it/800x670" class="image" alt="" data-target="#myModal"></div>
```

And here is javascript for swipe feature:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
                    // Swipe feature
                     $("#myCarousel").swiperight(function() {  
                      $("#myCarousel").carousel('prev');  
                    });  
                     $("#myCarousel").swipeleft(function() {  
                      $("#myCarousel").carousel('next');  
                     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write several methods / functions for each task.

```
var yourApp = window.yourApp || {};

yourApp.initModal = function (options) {
   $('a.js-modal').on('click' function (event) {
      $('#myModal').modal(options);
      event.preventDefault();
   }); 
};

yourApp.loadModalContent = function () {
   var content = $("#modalContent").html();

   if (content.length) {
       $('#myModal').html(content);
   }
};

yourApp.initCarouselSwipe = function (options) {
   $("#myCarousel")
      .carousel(options)
      .swiperight(function() {  
          $(this).carousel('prev');  
      }) 
      .swipeleft(function() {  
          $(this).carousel('next');  
      });
};

$(function() {
    yourApp.initModal({
        show: function () {
             yourApp.loadModalContent();
             yourApp.initCarouselSwipe();
        }
    });
});
```

1. One to open the modal with a callback that does load your dynamic content
2. The content loader should retrieve the modal's selector and put the content into
3. Last but not least we have to init the swipe events and the carousel

Comment: And how should html within modal look like? 

Right now it is loading static image like in example above.

Comment: yourApp.loadModalContent can return html from an AJAX call (would be the best) or from a DOM node (not a good practice)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I have just added your code to my above mentioned example but still anything is happening. At the modal window I have removed static image loading and leaved src="" in order to fill that space with ajax.

Comment: It does not work, because I just gave you a skeleton... you have to finish the methods for yourself. This platform is about question/anwser and not let other do your work... :-)

Comment: Ohh. :) Sry I am noob at js. Anyway will try it one more time.

Comment: thank you very much :))) I am still confused with modal and static image. Should I change my html dom structure or it can stay like this? One more thing, it fires modal window immediately when I refresh the page and the content is not changed when I do the swipe thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62671/discussion-between-redaxmedia-and-ninja-kornjaca).